# R-Dataframe : mean by row on all the DF with conditionnal on other column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, mean

I begin by the code that i want to have (all is write with example)

```
df <- data.frame(comp = c(10, 12, 14, 17, 17),
                 val = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20),
                 cond_inf = c(8, 9.6, 11.2, 13.6, 13.6),
                 cond_sup = c(12, 14.4, 16.8, 20.4, 20.4),
                 mean_cond_text1 = c("Average of VAL lines whose COMP is between 8 12", 
                                     "Average of VAL lines whose COMP is between 9.6 14.4",
                                     "Average of VAL lines whose COMP is between 11.2 16.8",
                                     "Average of VAL lines whose COMP is between 13.6 20.4", 
                                     "Average of VAL lines whose COMP is between 13.6 20.4"),
                 mean_cond_text2 = c("(val_row1+val_row2)/2", "(val_row1+val_row2+val_row3)/3", "(val_row2+val_row3)/2", "(val_row3+val_row4+val_row5)/2", "(val_row3+val_row4+val_row5)/2)"),
                 mean_cond_text3 = c("(0+5)/2", "(0+5+10)/3", "(5+10)/2", "(10+15+20)/3", "(10+15+20)/3)"),
                 mean_cond_num = c((0+5)/2, (0+5+10)/3, (5+10)/2, (10+15+20)/3, (10+15+20)/3))
```

I wish on each line of a dataframe to calculate the average of a column VAL, for all the lines whose COMP comparison values ​​are included in a COND_INF - COND_SUP interval of my line on which I calculate the average. So there is an average to calculate on each line of my data frame.

In a Dataframe, each row with 4 columns all the time filled in

COMP = the column on which the condition will be applied to take the line into account or not in the calculation of the average

VAL = the value that will be used to calculate the average if the line is taken into account

COND_INF = the lower bound (-20% of COMP) whose COMP must be higher-equal to be taken into account

COND_SUP = the upper limit (+ 20% of COMP) whose COMP must be lower-equal to be taken into account

Thank you, for your help, I'm lost...

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about the approach desired, but this seems to be close to what you might be looking for.

Looking at your data frame, it is unclear how rows 3 through 5 were calculated. For example, row 3 has `comp` of 14. That should be in range for rows 2-5, not just 2 and 3? Rows 4 and 5 have range (13.6, 20.4) and should be included in calculation for `comp` of 14? I also get a different mean value for rows 4 and 5 as well.

Let me know if my understanding is incorrect. Based on my impressions so far, here is one approach. I suspect there are better alternative ways using `data.table`, `sqldf`, etc.

```
df <- data.frame(comp = c(10, 12, 14, 17, 17),
                 val = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20),
                 cond_inf = c(8, 9.6, 11.2, 13.6, 13.6),
                 cond_sup = c(12, 14.4, 16.8, 20.4, 20.4))

library(dplyr)

# Add index for row number
df$idx <- seq(1, nrow(df))

# Split dataframe into comp and index and look up table with values and range
df1 <- df[c(1,5)]
df2 <- df[2:4]

# Expand grid to get multiple combinations and filter to those where comp in range 
expand_grid(df1, df2) %>%
  filter(between(comp, cond_inf, cond_sup)) %>%
  group_by(idx) %>%
  mutate(mean_cond_num = mean(val)) %>%
  right_join(df)

   comp   idx   val cond_inf cond_sup mean_cond_num
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>
1    10     1     0      8       12             2.5
2    12     2     5      9.6     14.4           5  
3    14     3    10     11.2     16.8          12.5
4    17     4    15     13.6     20.4          17.5
5    17     5    20     13.6     20.4          17.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
With your idea, i did

```
df <- data.frame(comp = c(10, 12, 14, 17, 17),
                 val = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20),
                 cond_inf = c(8, 9.6, 11.2, 13.6, 13.6),
                 cond_sup = c(12, 14.4, 16.8, 20.4, 20.4),
                 mean_cond_num = c((0+5)/2, (0+5+10)/3, (5+10)/2, (10+15+20)/3, (10+15+20)/3))

df$id <- seq(1, nrow(df))
df2 <- sqldf("SELECT a.*, b.val as val2, b.cond_inf as cond_inf2, b.cond_sup as cond_sup2
       FROM df as a, df as b
       where a.cond_inf <= b.comp
          and a.cond_sup >= b.comp")

df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(id, mean_cond_num) %>%
  summarise(mmoy = mean(val2))
```

It works, i have to try if on my real data, it's ok with the calculate time.
If its'ok, i'll come back to put resolve.
Thank you